# Extracting Details from Google Earth KML File in R

Tags: r, kml, rvest, r-sf

I am trying to take the details from a series of locations in a Google Earth kml file.

Getting the ids and coordinates works but for the name of location (which is located in the first table cell (td tag) of the Description), when I do it for ALL the locations, it returns the same value for all of them (Stratford Road - the name of the first location).

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

removeHtmlTags <- function(htmlString) {
  return(gsub("<.*?>", "", htmlString))
}
getHtmlTableCells<- function(htmlString) {
  # Convert html to html doc
  htmldoc <- read_html(htmlString)
  # get html for each cell (i.e. within <td></td>)
  table_cells_with_tags <- html_nodes(htmldoc, "td")
  # remove the html tags (<td></td>)
  return(removeHtmlTags(table_cells_with_tags))[1]
}

download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohipb477kqrqtlz/AQMS_2019.kml?dl=1","aqms.kml")
locations <- st_read("aqms.kml", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  rename(id = Name) %>%
  mutate(latitude = st_coordinates(geometry)[,1],
         longitiude = st_coordinates(geometry)[,2],
         name = getHtmlTableCells(Description)[1]) %>%
  st_drop_geometry()
```

Now if I use the function on a particular location and get the first table cell (td), then it works, returning Stratford Road and Selly Oak for the first as below.

```
getHtmlTableCells(locations$Description[1])[1]
getHtmlTableCells(locations$Description[2])[1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read_html` is not vectorised - it does not accept a vector of different html to parse. We can `apply` your function over each element of the vector:

```r
locations <- st_read("aqms.kml", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

locations %>%
  rename(id = Name) %>%
  mutate(latitude = st_coordinates(geometry)[,1],
         longitiude = st_coordinates(geometry)[,2],
         name = sapply(Description, function(x) getHtmlTableCells(x)[1])) %>%
  st_drop_geometry()

#>     latitude longitiude                      name
#> 1  -1.871622   52.45920            Stratford Road
#> 2  -1.934559   52.44513  Selly Oak (Bristol Road)
#> 3  -1.830070   52.43771              Acocks Green
#> 4  -1.898731   52.48180               Colmore Row
#> 5  -1.896764   52.48607        St Chads Queensway
#> 6  -1.891955   52.47990     Moor Street Queensway
#> 7  -1.918173   52.48138       Birmingham Ladywood
#> 8  -1.902121   52.47675       Lower Severn Street
#> 9  -1.786413   52.56815                  New Hall
#> 10 -1.874989   52.47609 Birmingham A4540 Roadside
```

Alternatively, since you're making use of *regex* anyway within your function, you could make use of `stringr::str_extract` to extract your text (which is already vectorised).

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

locations <- st_read("aqms.kml", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  rename(id = Name) %>%
  mutate(latitude = st_coordinates(geometry)[,1],
         longitiude = st_coordinates(geometry)[,2],
         name = str_extract(Description, '(?<=Location</td> <td>)[^<]+')) %>%
  st_drop_geometry()
```

Where `(?<=Location</td> <td>)` is a lookbehind for the *Location* td tag that precedes our *name*, and `[^<]+` matches anything up to the next tag following the *name*.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Chris. Out of interest, whereabouts in the World are you?

Comment: No problem. Based in London :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `getHtmlTableCells` function isn't vectorized. If you pass it a single html string, it works fine, but if you pass it multiple strings it will only process the first. Also, you have put a [1] *after* the return statement, which doesn't do anything. It needs to be inside the brackets. One you do this, it is easy to vectorize the function using `sapply`.

So make a tiny change in your function...

```r
getHtmlTableCells <- function(htmlString) {
  # Convert html to html doc
  htmldoc <- read_html(htmlString)
  # get html for each cell (i.e. within <td></td>)
  table_cells_with_tags <- html_nodes(htmldoc, "td")
  # remove the html tags (<td></td>)
  return(removeHtmlTags(table_cells_with_tags)[1])
}
```

and vectorize it like this:

```r
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohipb477kqrqtlz/AQMS_2019.kml?dl=1","aqms.kml")

locations <- st_read("aqms.kml", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  rename(id = Name) %>%
  mutate(latitude = st_coordinates(geometry)[,1],
         longitiude = st_coordinates(geometry)[,2],
         name = sapply(as.list(Description), getHtmlTableCells)) %>%
  st_drop_geometry()
```

Which gives the correct result:

```r
locations$name
#>  [1] "Stratford Road"            "Selly Oak (Bristol Road)" 
#>  [3] "Acocks Green"              "Colmore Row"              
#>  [5] "St Chads Queensway"        "Moor Street Queensway"    
#>  [7] "Birmingham Ladywood"       "Lower Severn Street"      
#>  [9] "New Hall"                  "Birmingham A4540 Roadside"
```